# How to set 404 on joomla?

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-404

I have a problem. I have absolutely clean new joomla 2.5.19 on my localhost.
What we have:
http://localhost/joomla/ - main page
http://localhost/joomla/?ferfrefr - main page too.
How to set 404 page for http://localhost/joomla/?dewdew ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Philipp Klemeshov**,

With Joomla, you can use very popular [sh404SEF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sh404sef) extension to easily manage 404 urls of site and you can also redirect specific url to any selected page also. It will also give you excellent and powefull SEF url functionality with Joomla!

Have a fun with it!

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Thanks, 
Mrunal.